# Fill aesthetic not working while using geom_count

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to set the fill to of my ggplot object to NA. I've done it before using similar code but for some reason this code isn't working. Any ideas?

Here's my data:

```
structure(list(longitude = c(-81.09397, -81.09397, -81.09397, 
-81.09397, -81.09397, -81.15897, -81.15897, -81.15897, -81.15897, 
-81.15897, -81.15897, -81.17191, -81.17538, -81.17191, -81.17538, 
-81.17191, -81.17538, -81.17191, -81.17538, -81.17191, -81.17538, 
-81.16389, -81.17191, -81.17538, -81.17191, -81.17538, -81.17191, 
-81.17538, -81.16389, -81.17191, -81.17538, -81.16389, -81.17191, 
-81.17538, -81.16389, -81.17191, -81.16127, -81.16389, -81.17191, 
-81.16389, -81.17191, -81.16127, -81.17191, -81.17191, -81.25841, 
-81.25841, -81.25841, -81.24818, -81.25841, -81.25841, -81.25841, 
-81.25841, -81.25841, -81.24818, -81.25841, -81.25841, -81.24818, 
-81.25841, -81.25841, -81.25841, -81.24818, -81.25841, -81.24818, 
-81.25841, -81.24818, -81.25841, -81.24818, -81.25841, -81.24818, 
-81.25841, -81.24818, -81.25841, -81.24818, -81.25841, -81.26803, 
-81.24818, -81.25841, -81.24818, -81.25841, -81.24818, -81.25841, 
-81.24818, -81.23814, -81.25841, -81.24818, -81.25841, -81.24818, 
-81.24818, -81.24818, -81.24818, -81.25841, -81.24818, -81.25841, 
-81.24818, -81.24818, -81.24818, -81.24818, -81.24818, -81.25841
), latitude = c(72.35019, 72.35019, 72.35019, 72.35019, 72.35019, 
72.32544, 72.32544, 72.32544, 72.32544, 72.32544, 72.32544, 72.294, 
72.2963, 72.294, 72.2963, 72.294, 72.2963, 72.294, 72.2963, 72.294, 
72.2963, 72.29368, 72.294, 72.2963, 72.294, 72.2963, 72.294, 
72.2963, 72.29368, 72.294, 72.2963, 72.29368, 72.294, 72.2963, 
72.29368, 72.294, 72.29111, 72.29368, 72.294, 72.29368, 72.294, 
72.29111, 72.294, 72.294, 72.26846, 72.26846, 72.26846, 72.26533, 
72.26846, 72.26846, 72.26846, 72.26846, 72.26846, 72.26533, 72.26846, 
72.26846, 72.26533, 72.26846, 72.26846, 72.26846, 72.26533, 72.26846, 
72.26533, 72.26846, 72.26533, 72.26846, 72.26533, 72.26846, 72.26533, 
72.26846, 72.26533, 72.26846, 72.26533, 72.26846, 72.27166, 72.26533, 
72.26846, 72.26533, 72.26846, 72.26533, 72.26846, 72.26533, 72.26213, 
72.26846, 72.26533, 72.26846, 72.26533, 72.26533, 72.26533, 72.26533, 
72.26846, 72.26533, 72.26846, 72.26533, 72.26533, 72.26533, 72.26533, 
72.26533, 72.26846)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(36499L, 
36501L, 36518L, 36527L, 37049L, 37812L, 37816L, 37818L, 37820L, 
37826L, 37829L, 37943L, 37944L, 37945L, 37946L, 37947L, 37948L, 
37950L, 37951L, 37953L, 37954L, 37955L, 37956L, 37957L, 37958L, 
37959L, 37960L, 37961L, 37962L, 37963L, 37964L, 37966L, 37967L, 
37968L, 37969L, 37971L, 37972L, 37973L, 37974L, 37975L, 37976L, 
37977L, 37978L, 37979L, 37990L, 38007L, 38014L, 38016L, 38017L, 
38023L, 38028L, 38031L, 38032L, 38036L, 38037L, 38041L, 38042L, 
38045L, 38048L, 38049L, 38052L, 38053L, 38054L, 38055L, 38056L, 
38057L, 38058L, 38059L, 38060L, 38061L, 38062L, 38063L, 38064L, 
38065L, 38067L, 38068L, 38069L, 38072L, 38073L, 38074L, 38075L, 
38076L, 38077L, 38079L, 38080L, 38081L, 38082L, 38083L, 38084L, 
38086L, 38088L, 38090L, 38091L, 38094L, 38095L, 38096L, 38097L, 
38098L, 38209L))
```

And here's my current code:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_count(data = DetsIND, aes( x = longitude, y = latitude), color = 'black', fill = NA)+
  xlim(-81.4, -80.55)+ ylim( 72.2, 72.7)
```

Comment: I think the default shape doesn't have a fill. Try using `shape = 1`.

Comment: @Lyngbakr huh, interesting. That works. Feel free to put it as the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default shape, 19, doesn't have a fill, so the parameter is ignored.

```r
# Dummy data frame
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1, 10), y = rep(1, 10))

# Load library
library(ggplot2)

# Plot data
g <- ggplot(df) + geom_count(aes(x, y), colour = "black", fill = NA)
g
```

[image]

Whereas, `shape = 1` *does* have a fill option.

```r
# Plot data
g <- ggplot(df) + geom_count(aes(x, y), colour = "black", fill = NA, shape = 1)
g
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

A full list of shapes can be found at the bottom of the page [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_shape.html).